# How to write using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How to write below code in underscore.js.

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.hList.h.length; i++) {
  if (res.hList.h[i].code == code) {
    res.hList.h[i].packList.pack = d.h.packList.pack;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [underscore documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#each) for the collections function, `each`.

```
_.forEach(response.hotelList.hotel, function (hotel) {
    if (hotel.code === code) {
        hotel.availablePackageList.package = data.hotel.availablePackageList.package;
    }
})
```

In ES6, the syntax will be very similar (and you should probably learn it):

```
response.hotelList.hotel.forEach(function (hotel) {
    if (hotel.code === code) {
        hotel.availablePackageList.package = data.hotel.availablePackageList.package;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use findWhere, since you are breaking after the first found. Try something like this:

```
_.findWhere(response.hotelList.hotel, {code :yourcode}).availablePackageList.package = data.hotel.availablePackageList.package;
```

Answer (score 0):

_.findWhere looks through the list you've provided and returns the first item that matches your specification.

```
var match = _.findWhere(response.hotelList.hotel, { code: code })
match.availablePackageList.package = data.hotel.availablePackageList.package;
```

http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere

Answer (score -1):

```js
var response = {
  hotelList: {
    hotel: [
        { availablePackageList: { package: 1 }, code: 1 },
        { availablePackageList: { package: 2 }, code: 2 },
        { availablePackageList: { package: 3 }, code: 3 },
        { availablePackageList: { package: 4 }, code: 4 }
    ]
  }
};

var data = {
  hotel: {
     availablePackageList: { package: 42 }
  }
};

var code = 3;

// This code will iterate over all hotels
_.each(response.hotelList.hotel, function(hotel) {
  if (hotel.code == code) {
    hotel.availablePackageList.package = data.hotel.availablePackageList.package;
  }
});

/* Preferred solution: find first occurrence

// find hotel with code 3
var foundHotel = _.find(response.hotelList.hotel, function(hotel) {
  return hotel.code == code;
});

// if found - update package
if (foundHotel) {
    foundHotel.availablePackageList.package = data.hotel.availablePackageList.package;
}

*/

document.write('<pre>');
document.write(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
document.write('</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @bob-sponge, is there any way to combine both in one function ?

Comment: @bob-sponge, it's convert in to Array, not keep object. **response**
Object {transaction: Object, totalRecords: 148, hotelList: Object}
**foundHotel**
Array[148]

Comment: Sorry, I saved wrong code. Result will be in `response`.